# Finding the expected value of a stochastic process?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Here is the question:

Let X(t)=At+B, where A and B are independent Normal distributions N(0,$\sigma^2$).  Find the expected value of the following Random Variables:

(A)  $Y_1 = max_{0 \leq t \leq1}X(t)$
(B)  $Y_2 = max_{0 \leq t \leq1} |X(t)|$
(C)  $Y_3 = \int_{0}^{1} X(t) dt$
(D)  $Y_4 = \int_{0}^{1} X^2(t) dt$

For the first part, I have figured out that the maximum will only happen at t=1 or t=0.  So if A<0, then the max will be B, and if A>0, then the max will be A+B.  But I don't know how to turn that into an equation in terms of Y, and get an expected value out of it.  I suspect that the first two are going to involve a simple use of the indicator function, but I'm not sure how to use it.

For the third and fourth one, I really want to just plug and chug, but I know that is wrong.  If you really want to help me out without giving me any answers, just showing me how to get the expected value of X may help.  I appreciate any tips and help I can get.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: For $Y_1$, note that 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(Y_1) &= \mathbb{E}\left[\left(A+B\right)1_{A>0}+B1_{A<0}\right]
\end{align}
where $1_A$ is the indicator function on the set $A$.

For $Y_2$ try to use the same reasonaning as in $Y_1$.

For $Y_3,Y_4$ I can't see why it is not a "plug and chung" (in this case).